# JAVA / SqLite memory behaves not as expected, rows are lost

Tags: java, sqlite

I have the following code using sqlite3 and java which runs without errors:

```
    public class SqLiteDB {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SqLiteDB theDatabase = SqLiteDB.initSqLiteDB();
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test", "beam process");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test", "beam process 1");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test", "beam process 2");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test1", "beam process 1");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test1", "beam process 2");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test2", "beam process");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test2", "beam process 1");
        theDatabase.addParametersRow("test3", "beam process");
        theDatabase.addGroupStatements();
        for (final Entry<String, String> result : theDatabase.getParametersAll().entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(result.getKey() + ", " + result.getValue() + "\n");
        }
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqLiteDB.class);

    private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private static SqLiteDB myInstance = null;

    // *****************************************************************************************************************
    // Public methods
    // *****************************************************************************************************************
    public static SqLiteDB initSqLiteDB() {
        if (myInstance == null) {
            myInstance = new SqLiteDB();
        }

        return myInstance;
    }

    public void addParametersRow(final String parameterName, final String beamProcessName) {
        final String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO PARAMETERS (PARAMETER_NAME, BEAM_PROCESS) VALUES ('" + parameterName
                + "', '" + beamProcessName + "');";
        try (Statement insertStatement = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
            insertStatement.execute(sqlInsert);
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.logError(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParametersAll() {
        final String sqlGetParameterCount = "SELECT * FROM PARAMETERS";
        final Map<String, String> queryResults = new TreeMap<>();
        try (Statement queryParameterCount = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
            final ResultSet resultSet = queryParameterCount.executeQuery(sqlGetParameterCount);
            getClass();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                queryResults.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2));
            }
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.logError(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        }

        return queryResults;
    }

    // *****************************************************************************************************************
    // Private methods
    // *****************************************************************************************************************
    private SqLiteDB() {
        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.logError(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        }

        createTableAvailableParameters();
    }

    private void createTableAvailableParameters() {
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            final String sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PARAMETERS (\n"
                    + " PARAMETER_NAME text NOT NULL, BEAM_PROCESS text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (PARAMETER_NAME, BEAM_PROCESS));";
            try (final Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
                statement.execute(sqlCreateTable);
            } catch (final SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void addGroupStatements() {
        final String sqlGetParameterCount = "SELECT PARAMETER_NAME, COUNT(PARAMETER_NAME) FROM PARAMETERS GROUP BY PARAMETER_NAME HAVING COUNT(PARAMETER_NAME) > 1";
        final Map<String, Integer> queryResults = new HashMap<>();
        try (Statement queryParameterCount = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
            final ResultSet resultSet = queryParameterCount.executeQuery(sqlGetParameterCount);
            getClass();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                queryResults.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getInt(2));
            }
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            ErrorLogger.logError(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        }

        for (final Entry<String, Integer> resultRow : queryResults.entrySet()) {
            if (resultRow.getValue() > 1) {
                addParametersRow(resultRow.getKey(), "*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code it produces the following output:

```
test, *
test1, *
test2, *
test3, beam process
```

I do not understand where my rows with "test(1,2), beam process(1,2)" are? Why / where are they lost?

Stackoverflow does not accept post with a lot of code. I wouldn't know how to truncate the code without omitting details which might be necessary. That's why I have to put in some more useless text. I hope it helps to make the question postable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss happens in the function `getParametersAll()`. In this function, you iterate over the available results and add them to a Map. However, if duplicate values occur, you override the already read results in the map. Thus, you only get the last created beam process for each of the parameters.

One way to solve this would be to create a `Map<String, List<String>>` and return this map instead.

```
Map<String, List<String>> queryResults = new TreeMap<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    if (!queryResults.contains(resultSet.getString(1)) {
        queryResults.put(resultSet.getString(1), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    queryResults.get(resultSet.getString(1)).add(resultSet.getString(2));
}
```

I hope, this answers your question, otherwise I have probably misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Illedhar's answer - thanks to that - I implemented the method getParametersAll using the Guava Multimap interface. Here the working code:

```
public Multimap<String, String> getParametersAll() {
    final String sqlGetParameterCount = "SELECT * FROM PARAMETERS";
    final Multimap<String, String> queryResults = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    try (Statement queryParameterCount = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
        final ResultSet resultSet = queryParameterCount.executeQuery(sqlGetParameterCount);
        getClass();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            queryResults.put(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2));
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (final SQLException ex) {
        ErrorLogger.logError(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
    }

return queryResults;
}
```

The output in the main method needs to be changed sightly too:

```
for (final Entry<String, String> result : theDatabase.getParametersAll().entries()) {
    System.out.print(result.getKey() + ", " + result.getValue() + "\n");
}
```

For cudos please vote 1+ for Illedhar.